# how to input single data in insert query

Tags: php, mysql

The error is:-

> Field 'attn' doesn't have a default value41

If I set all the value of column query run perfectly like :

```
$stuattend = "INSERT INTO tblattendance(roll, attandence, att_time) VALUES('$roll', 'present', '5:30')";
```

I guess my problem is when I execute **one value (roll)** through query.

What would be the solution?

Comment: check your database. maybe attendance field is set as not null. give a default value of attendance field like `absent`. and your code will work.

Comment: what code are you using when it's not working?

Comment: It seems you have "attn" column in your database, not "attandence" like you specified in your query.

Comment: my problem is I want to insert one value and other value remain empty. Like three input value- roll, date, time, I want only insert roll. my quary "insert into tableName(roll) values ('$_POST['roll']). but I am getting error message. what would be query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi the error clearly states that you have a column named as **attn** which is not **nullable** field by default. Either provide the default value or make it nullable or pass it some value so that it stops throwing the error.

You can change the above query to assign the default value as follows :

NOTE : Here you may assign the any value to it. Thinking that it may be integer I am doing as follows

```
INSERT INTO tblattendance(roll, attandence, att_time, attn) VALUES('$roll', 'present', '5:30', 10)
```

Comment: Hi @Student if my answer has help you then can you please mark is as accepted. So that it may help other too to find the solution easily